# error:0308010C:digital when trying to deploy to firebase hosting via Github push

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, firebase-hosting, react-scripts

I can push to the firebase live site with "firebase deploy" command in terminal just fine, however when I want to push to main so it auto updates this is what is displayed on the deploy failed on Github

```
Run yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports
```

Comment: what's your node version and react version you're using ?

Comment: @monim we are currently using node v16 and 17.0.2 for react

Comment: Ive also tried a few of those solutions listed

Comment: try updating **react-script** to THE LATEST VERSION . in the terminal run `yarn upgrade --latest react-scripts`

Comment: Updating react scripts to 5.0.1 did the trick, found it on the thread you posted thank you @monim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error occurs when you use **Node.js of version 17+** and use **OpenSSL v3.0** which has some major changes in its algorithm.  since you are using
Create React App applications, just upgrade `react-scripts to v5.0.0 or higher` will solve the issue .

for **npm** users  run  :

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```

for **yarn** users run  :

```
yarn upgrade --latest react-scripts
```